# Using inserted jsp page's request instead of main jsp page's request

Tags: jsp, servlets, request

The title may be a bit misleading since I couldn't figure a better one.

I'm working on two jsp pages. One handles the main frame, and the other is used to show content (at this time, a single image, but it may change later). I want to include the second page (which has the content) into the first page (which is the main frame), using something like this:

```
<jsp:directive.include file="includes/myContentPage.jsp" />
```

(this is inside the main page).

However, this content page is handled by a servlet. This servlet assigns all the relevant data to the request, and the content page uses it as ${myAttribute}, like this:

```
<img style="margin-right: 30px; margin-top: 30px;" src="${myAttribute}" />
```

When I call the servlet (and thus the jsp content page) it shows correctly (because it uses his own request with the proper attributes), but when I call the main page (the one including the content page) it doesn't work properly. In my case, it doesn't have a "myAttribute" attribute in the request and thus, no attribute is passed to the, in this case, img's src tag.

I think I understand why this is caused (using the main frame page's request instead of the content page's request) and the fact that the content request doesn't truly has a request (since the servlet uses the page and not the other way around), so, is there any ways to solve this? Can I, somehow, tell the page to use this servlet when called (althought I tried forwarding it, it results in a endless loop because the page and the servlet calls them each other).

Is there any other solution? Keep in mind I can't touch some stuff (like the main frame page's request), but anything related to the content page can be modified (including the servlet). Maybe including the page in a different way instead of simply including it as a file is the solution?

Some relevant code

Servlet handler

```
request.setAttribute("myAttribute", myAttribute);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/.../myContentPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Servlet definition

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/myContentServlet" }, name="myContentServlet")
```

Comment: Well, don't include the second JSP. Include the servlet that generates the attributes for the second JSP and then forwards to it: main.jsp -- includes --> second servlet -- forwards to --> second.jsp

Comment: I tried doing that, but forwarding to the second servlet changes the whole page to the second page, showing just the content. Or by "including the servlet" you meant a different operation than forwarding with a RequestDispatcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some thought, I couldn't come with an answer, so I simply stopped using a servlet and used a spring bean to inject the content properties into the first jsp page, and discarded the second one. I could've still used the second jsp with the same spring values into the page.